# insert ... returning where X

Tags: postgresql

hi i have an issue im trying to solve using the following to do a insert statement

```
begin;
with t1 as (values (2),(3),(4))

,in1 as (insert into table123 (id,val,num)
select nextval('table123_id_seq'),t1.val,42
from t1
on conflict do nothing returning *)

,ins2 as (insert into table456 (id,num,fkey_id)
select nextval('table234_id_seq'),333, (select table123.id from table123 where val = 2)
from in1
on conflict do nothing returning *)
;commit;
```

what I get is 3 entries into table456 where I want only one

is there a clever way to do returning where X or something similar to avoid the duplication?

currently i workround just divide the insert through 2 queries ins1a with val=2 and ins1b with t1.v

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Create a db<>fiddle (https://dbfiddle.uk/) or similar so that the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: http://rextester.com/FFAFN16894 something simple to demonstrate the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for

```
begin;
with t1(val) as (values (2),(3),(4))

,in1 as (insert into table123 (id,val,num)
select nextval('table123seq'),t1.val,42
from t1
on conflict do nothing returning *)

,ins2 as (insert into table456 (id,num,fkey_id)
select nextval('table456seq'),333, in1.id 
from in1 where in1.val = 2
on conflict do nothing returning *)
commit;
```

Comment: perfect, I knew i was missing something simple! this fixes everything nicely

Answer (score 1):

There's an awful lot to be said for keeping things simple:

```
begin;

insert into table123 ( id, val, num ) values ( nextval('table123seq'), 2, 42 ); 
insert into table123 ( id, val, num ) values ( nextval('table123seq'), 3, 42 ); 
insert into table123 ( id, val, num ) values ( nextval('table123seq'), 4, 42 ); 

insert into table456 ( id, num, fkey_id ) 
   select next( 'table546seq' ), 333, id 
   from table123 
   where table213.num = 2 ; 

select * from table456 ; 
commit ;
```

Alternatively, make your id columns auto-increment and forget all about them entirely.

If that's *not* what you're after, then a plain-English description of the Problem you're trying to solve - *not* the difficulties with your current attempt at solving it - would be a good place to start.

Comment: that is just a tiny example code of a massive insert segment that is doing data load into a database, irl im loading 15000 fields into ~15 tables so that solution is unfortunately unworkable